# How to get second part of a url by splitting or parsing while page.evaluate oeprating

Tags: javascript, node.js, split, html-parsing, url-parsing

Assume that, I have
*countries/eg

countries/us

countries/gr

etc.*

I want to take only country code part as a string for each item in *details* as *cc*. But I want to do that during the page.evaluate operation. In my code I had *undefined* for each item in this case. How can I do that? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
getDetails: async (lineBaseSelector) => {
        try {

            let url = await page.url();

            function parseUrl( url ) {
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                a.href = url;
                return a;
            }
            
            const details = await page.evaluate((x) => {
                const data = {
                    cc : parseUrl(document.querySelector(`${x}`).getAttribute('href').toLowerCase()).search,
                    name: document.querySelector(`${x}`).innerText.toLowerCase(),
                    url: document.querySelector(`${x}`).getAttribute('href'),
                    last_update: Date.now()
                }
                return Promise.resolve(data);
            }, lineBaseSelector);

            return details;

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 const data = {
                    cc : document.querySelector(`${x}`).getAttribute('href').toLowerCase().toString().split("/")[1],
                    name: document.querySelector(`${x}`).innerText.toLowerCase(),
                    url: document.querySelector(`${x}`).getAttribute('href'),
                    last_update: Date.now()
                }
```

It is possible with split oepration. In here, index is 1 because of the first part of url has index of 0th.